# Laravel controller function not found

Tags: php, laravel

Currently I'm working with laravel. When I want to acces a controller through the view. I receive the error that my method is not found.

> Action App\Http\Controllers\RidesController@edit not defined. (View:
>   C:\wamp\www\resources\views\rides\rides.blade.php)

But when I try the index method it works strange enough? What should I do?

This is my rides.blade.php:

```
  </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                 <tbody>
                                    @foreach($rides as $ride)
                                     <tr>
                                        <td><a href="{!! action('RidesController@edit',$ride->id) !!}">{!! $ride->id !!}</a> </td>
                                        <td>{!! $ride->created_at !!}</td>
                                        <td>{!! $ride->beginstand !!}</td>
                                        <td>{!! $ride->eindstand !!}</td>
                                        <td>{!! $ride->van !!}</td>
                                        <td>{!! $ride->naar !!}</td>
                                        <td>{!! $ride->bezoekadres !!}</td>
                                        <td>{!! $ride->geredenroute !!}</td>
                                        <td>{!! $ride->karakterrit !!}</td>
                                        <td>{!! $ride->toelichting !!}</td>
                                        <td>{!! $ride->kilometerszakelijk !!}</td>
                                        <td>{!! $ride->kilometersprive !!}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                     @endforeach
                                </tbody>
```

And my routes controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\models\ridesregistration;
use App\Http\Requests\RideFormRequest;

class RidesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $rides = ridesregistration::all();
        return view("rides.rides",compact('rides'));
    }

    public function create() 
    {
        return view('rides.create');
    }

    public function store(rideFormRequest $request)
    {
        $rides = new ridesregistration(array(
            'beginstand' =>$request->get('beginstand'),
            'eindstand' =>$request->get('eindstand'),
            'van' =>$request->get('van'),
            'naar' =>$request->get('naar'),
            'bezoekadres' =>$request->get('bezoekadres'),
            'geredenroute' =>$request->get('geredenroute'),
            'karakterrit' =>$request->get('karakterrit'),
            'toelichting' =>$request->get('toelichting'),
            'kilometerszakelijk' =>$request->get('kilometerszakelijk'),
            'kilometersprive' =>$request->get('kilometersprive')
            ));
        $rides->save();
        return redirect('/maakrit')->with('message','Rit '.$rides->id.' is succesvol aangemaakt.');
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $rides = ridesregistration::whereId($id)->firstOrFail();
        return view('rides.edit',compact('rides','rides'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using lowercase names for your model directory and class names? The convention is clearly CamelCase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to laravel 5 documentaion
http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers

u should use namespacing with action() helper

http://joxi.ru/8AnBMZXSv8lpAO

if we will dig deeper into \Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::action

we`ll see:

```
public function action($action, $parameters = [], $absolute = true)
{
    if ($this->rootNamespace && !(strpos($action, '\\') === 0)) {
        $action = $this->rootNamespace.'\\'.$action;
    } else {
        $action = trim($action, '\\');
    }

    if (!is_null($route = $this->routes->getByAction($action))) {
        return $this->toRoute($route, $parameters, $absolute);
    }

    throw new InvalidArgumentException("Action {$action} not defined.");
}
```

that your action('RidesController@index') works because it is defined in routes.
and your action('RidesController@edit',$ride->id) not work becouse it is not in the routes.

define this controller action in your app/Http/routes.php

Comment: thanks for your reply. But how is it possible that I can acces RidesController@index but not RidesController@edit?